# Cascading parameters with an all records returned option in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am not new to SSRS but haven't touched it in 3 years.  I have a report where I have two cascading parameters:

State (state abbreviations in the recordset) and a Vendor List that populates based on what is chosen.  I have the StateCode as the parameter and same for value.  I have chosen for both the parameters to allow Blanks.

I'm trying to create an ALL records option on the State parameter, then if they choose ALL records, then a chance to either choose the Vendor or leave it ALL records as well.

I have a tablix that I have filters on for the parameters and two different datasets to make it work.  I have in my recordset query a union with a NULL on both.

When I choose any state, the vendors for that state populate fine but when I leave a NULL or ALL option at the top, nothing returns.

Any way this can work so I can have the ALL option for the StateCode and Vendor and if the user choose "ALL" on both parameters that everything populates in the tablix?

Answer (score 0):

I just kept going with the params and read articles on the internet on how to solve it.  What I did was use cascading parms with multi-value and made sure my SQL was correct in my dataset and it finally worked.